# Icon only back button jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

Within my jQuery Mobile page I programmatically set up my back button to appear on every page that is not the first page by using the following code `<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="anid">` what this does is create a back button that have text in it saying back. however I do not want that I want the icon only.

How can this be done in jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ygmWD/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header a.ui-btn-left").addClass("ui-btn-icon-notext");
    $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header a.ui-btn-left").removeClass("ui-btn-icon-left");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 $(this).find('a[data-rel=back]').buttonMarkup({iconpos: 'notext'});
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Bjamh/)**

Answer (score 0):

for me this one worked:

```
data-iconpos="notext"
```

Example:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Regresar" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
```