# jQM Back Button with notext howto?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

My jQM App, I added "$.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;" to auto show back button on every page (except first page).

My question is, how to set the "notext" for the back button to show icon only?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header a.ui-btn-left").addClass("ui-btn-icon-notext");
    $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header a.ui-btn-left").removeClass("ui-btn-icon-left");
});
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4, `.buttonMarkup()` function is deprecated and will be removed in 1.5. Instead, on `pagecreate`, replace default class `ui-btn-icon-left` with `ui-btn-icon-notext`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {
    $("[data-rel=back]", e.target)
        .toggleClass("ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext");
});
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227297/icon-only-back-button-jquery-mobile/16231539#16231539) is for jQuery Mobile 1.3 and below.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xH66Q/)**

Comment: Hi @Omar, I'm sorry for cross-topic but I'm really urgently need to solve one of the problem to continue my work. Can you please have a look at this issue? Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119281/jqm-jquery-collageplus-usage-issue

Answer (score 1):

I get it done using Omar's suggestion:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 $(this).find('a[data-rel=back]').buttonMarkup({iconpos: 'notext'});
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: `buttonMarkup()` is deprecated in 1.4 and will be removed on 1.5.