# jQM / jquery-collagePlus Usage Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm building app using jQM and I'm trying to use jquery-collagePlus (http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/)

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5HfK/

My HTML:

```
<div class="collage">
    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food1.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food2.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food3.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food4.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food5.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food6.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food7.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food8.jpg">
                    <img src="http://mywaiter.my/images/food9.jpg">
                </div>
```

The JS:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $('.collage').collagePlus();
    });
```

It doesn't seem to work and because I'm new to JS, I'm not too sure why.

In my app test, all the images is gone after the jQM page loaded.

Please advice on what I have done wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Use `pagecontainershow` not `.load()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with jQuery Mobile you need to use appropriate jQuery Mobile page event, in this case it is showpage (jQuery Mobile 1.4 and below) or pagecontainershow (jQuery Mobile 1.4 and above).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/26WXB/4/

#### jQuery Mobile 1.4 and above

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {
    var activePage = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id');
    if(activePage === 'index') {
        $('.collage').collagePlus(
            {
                // change this to adjust the height of the rows
                'targetHeight' : 100,
                // change this to try different effects
                // valid effets = effect-1 to effect-6
                'effect' : "effect-1"
            }
        );   
    }
});
```

#### or jQuery Mobile 1.4 and below:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $('.collage').collagePlus(
        {
            // change this to adjust the height of the rows
            'targetHeight' : 100,
            // change this to try different effects
            // valid effets = effect-1 to effect-6
            'effect' : "effect-1"
        }
    );             
});
```

Comment: Hi Gajotres, thanks for your help. Your jsfiddle the image doesn't arrange as collage. The developer example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/uZv3n/

So how can I make it at my jQM page? Please advice, thank you.

Comment: I tried add in the developer example CSS and now it happen as my local app, all the images is gone. Here is the update of your example jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/lesliez/26WXB/2/

Comment: It works just fine, you are not using it properly. You forgot plugin CSS. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/26WXB/3/

Comment: Hi, when I load this jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/26WXB/3

This is what I see: http://mywaiter.my/images/jsfiddle.png

Comment: I don't understand you, you have only posted my previous jsFiddle example? Look at example I made out of your images: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/26WXB/4/

Comment: I really don't understand, you mentioned the image is working. When I load your jsfiddle, as my screen capture, the images are just blank. mywaiter.my/images/jsfiddle.png

Comment: This is because Chrome is God awful for jQuery Mobile testing. It refuses to load GitHub js files. Test it in Firefox or include js code directly into jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26WXB/5/

Comment: This I try to use firefox, images displayed, but not arranged at the developer demo. http://mywaiter.my/images/jsfiddle-firefox.png

Comment: Ok I got your info about Chrome. Will try to load the JS directly into jsfiddle. As what the developer do. Will update again. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what are you looking at but I'm seeing completely different picture:  http://example.gajotres.net/test.png

Comment: Hi Gajotres, finally got it working after copy and paste the JS into jsfiddle. Thank you so much for your help. I'll study the page carefully to under how it work. Thanks again.